# Page size of grid does not change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I use Devexpress grid and I have a dropdown for changing number of rows in the grid. But number of rows in the grid does not change. I put breakpoint in .cshtml file of grid and I see that variable pageSize has new value but grid does not change. Where might be the problem?

Here is my part of my grid definition:

```
@{  
    int initialSize = 10;
    int pageSize = ViewBag.PageSize ?? initialSize;
    var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(
        settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "gvCompanies";
            settings.Width = 960;
            settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { "Company", Action = "AllCompanies" };
            settings.SettingsPager.Mode = GridViewPagerMode.ShowPager;
            settings.SettingsPager.PageSize = pageSize;
            settings.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "CompanyBeginCallback";

            //... more settings

            //column definiton
        } );
    if ( Model != null )
    {
        grid.Bind( Model ).GetHtml();
    }
    else
    {
        grid.GetHtml();
    }
}
```

Dropdown change event function:

```
function ChangeRowsPerPage(s, e)
{
    s.Refresh();        
}
```

Grid begin callback function:

```
function CompanyBeginCallback(s, e) {
    e.customArgs["rowsPerPage"] = rowsCount.GetValue();
}
```

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult AllCompanies( int? rowsPerPage )
{
    //..some code
    ViewBag.PageSize = rowsPerPage;
    return PartialView( "CompanyGVPartial", data );
}
```